# Ensuring unique selection in two css3 select box filled with same categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

got two select boxes populated with same categories to do a filter. well, to provide two choices to broaden the result.

```
   $("#c_id1").change(function(){
    $("#c_id2 option:hidden").show();
    if($(this).val().length ){
      $("#c_id2 option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").hide();
    }
  });
  $("#c_id2").change(function(){
    $("#c_id1 option:hidden").show();
    if($(this).val().length ){
      $("#c_id1 option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").hide();
    }
  });
```

now, this script ensures a user can only select only one type of category from either of the two select box.

the problem:
**first** - when the page loads, options that are by default selected, the uniqueness only happens when user makes a selection. that is, this select box is populated with the seam categories. so the html select shows the first option by default in both the boxes. but when u actually make the selection, only then this script does it work.

**second** - if you got a pretty css3 drop down select box. the script wont work at all.

link to the bare bones version - http://jsfiddle.net/fh9Qp/ - just as proof of concept

link to what i am actually attempting - http://jsfiddle.net/G6hXr/

where is the actual problem. and how to sort this out.

Comment: Your first problem appears, because you only handle the change event of #c_id1 and #c_id2; you do not initialise anything. So nothing happens until a user changes something.

Comment: even if i initialize the select box, categories in both are not unique. only when a user makes a selection, the script works.

Comment: Ok, well show the code of your initialization, because something goes wrong there :)

Comment: i just put a "selected" in the box - http://jsfiddle.net/fh9Qp/1/